# Inserting a record with many columns into a MariaDB Columnstore table takes a long time

Tags: performance, mariadb, sql-insert, columnstore

I have a table with 50 columns in a MariaDB columnstore and it takes more than 5 seconds to insert a single record. I am very surprised to see this.

I am not sure if it is expected since there are too many columns or there could be some settings that I might have done wrong.

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
   id` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'autoincrement=1',
   // mostly int(10) and varchar(20) columns
) ENGINE=Columnstore DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi, I'm also using large data, I have MariaDB 10.1 I worked with InnoDB engine and when I changed to ARIA engine over innoDB... a had a MAJOR speed increase... The part I like best the the Full_text index. I did `ALTER TABLE table_name ADD FULLTEXT(column_name);` and to search phrases or just 1 word, it really increased speed ;)

Comment: Can you test with `ENGINE=ARIA` and tell me how much difference you have ?

Comment: We haven't tried with `ARIA` but we have with `InnoDB`, and it was quick as expected. We are stepping away from MariaDB as a choice of column data store and now evaluating `Clickhouse` instead. Performance wise, `Clickhouse` is very impressive.

Comment: @KinCheung, `Clickhouse` does indeed have very impressive performance, but it comes at the cost of features, as `UPDATE` and `DELETE` is not supported (yet). Supporting these while preserving the performance is going to be quite a challenge.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the way data is stored, it must unpack 50 compressed blobs, each holding up to 64K rows' worth of one column, add the new cell, then recompute the min, max, etc, and recompress it.

It is much better to gather lots of rows (thousands) and insert them all at once.  Then it might take not much more than 5 seconds for the entire batch, thereby being only an average of a few *milliseconds* per row.

Would you describe your application?  Columnstore is not the solution for everyone; it has a rather narrow niche.  Perhaps InnoDB would be better for your app.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We are looking for a data store that we can use to build dashboards and a BI frontend. We get thousands of machine generated records every second and we want to put them into such a store for ad hoc analysis, mostly simple aggregations and counts based on dates and a few other columns. We are also trying to keep the data as raw as possible and allow fast adhoc  queries without ETL.

Comment: "Thousands per second" is challenging.  And, if nothing is done to summarize the data, then ad hoc queries will need to scan millions for an hour's data.

Comment: You might want to try and buffer the inserts in a different table with InnoDB and to do micro batches to load the data. Another option would be to use the [ColumnStore Bulk Write API](https://mariadb.com/downloads/mariadb-ax/data-adapters) to directly insert the records.